# when I press on stop button or seek bar reach to the end this application stop working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

this is a simple application to play Audio file.Everything works great but have a one problem when I press on the stop button or the seek bar reach to the end My application stops working

note: before I connect the seek bar with the Media Player everything works well

this is my code:

```
public class SongActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private SongInfo song;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private int AudioFocusRequest;
    private int ProgressValue;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private Handler mSeekbarUpdateHandler = new Handler();


    // AudioManager Focus change Listener ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener onAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                releaseMediaplayer();
            } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK || focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
    };
    // SeekBar Change Listener ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                ProgressValue = progress;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(ProgressValue);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SongActivity.this, "اختار السوره اولا ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    //seekBar handler-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private Runnable mUpdateSeekbar = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(this, 50);
        }
    };

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releaseMediaplayer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }


    // MediaPlayer On completion Listener ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Toast.makeText(SongActivity.this, " السوره انتهت  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            releaseMediaplayer();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarChangeListener);


        final ArrayList<SongInfo> songList = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();

        songList.add(new SongInfo("الفاتحه", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.fatha));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("العصر", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elasr));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الاخلاص", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elekhlas));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الفلق", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elfalaq));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الفيل", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elfel));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الهمزه", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elhamza));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الكافرون", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elkaferon));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الكوثر", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elkawsr));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("قريش", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.qurish));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("المسد", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elmasad));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الماعون", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elmaaon));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("الناس", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elnas));
        songList.add(new SongInfo("النصر", "مشارى العفاسى", R.raw.elnasr));

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(SongActivity.this, songList);
        listView.setAdapter(songAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                song = songList.get(position);

                AudioFocusRequest = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                if (AudioFocusRequest == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    releaseMediaplayer();
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SongActivity.this, song.getSongResource());
                    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbar,0);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
                }
            }
        });

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AudioFocusRequest = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

                if (AudioFocusRequest == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
                    } else {
                        /*mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SongActivity.this, R.raw.fatha);
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                        mSeekbarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekbar,0);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);*/
                        Toast.makeText(SongActivity.this, "لتشغيل السوره التى تريدها اضغط عليها ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Button pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mSeekbarUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateSeekbar);
                    releaseMediaplayer();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void releaseMediaplayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? Also, please post the stack trace of the crash

Comment: It crashes when the stopButton is pressed or when the sound ends and the seekbar comes to an end